# How to integrate AWS Lex with Nodejs

Tags: amazon-lex

I want to know How can I integrate AWS Lex with the node?.

I need to implement:-
suppose I have a lex bot and i want to send a message to the lexbot from the nodejs and the response lexbot return sends it back to the front-end website.

```
I don not have any idea about it Please help me out.

Thanks!
```

Comment: YOU CAN FIND THE SOLUTION
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884804/how-do-i-initiate-a-conversation-with-aws-lex-from-node-js

Comment: Perhaps start here with this AWS Lex tutorial that will use CloudFront to deploy a Lex bot together with a web UI for users to chat with your bot.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.